# Selenium find.by

Tags: python, class, find, selector

Good day. I am starting to learn Selenium and I am a beginner. I have this problem: I need to select all head-to-head matches (for example, Djokovic-Alcaraz 2:1...) from the entire Tipsport site. There is a variable URL. Can someone help me with the code please? Thank you.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

driver.get("https://www.tipsport.cz/statistiky-zapasu/5543056/3873/43/false")


my_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "m-matchStatsMatchesIndicator__row")

matches_list = []

for matches in my_elements:

    name = matches.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "m-matchStatsMatchesIndicator__label")
    score = matches.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "m-statsRow__percentage")

    zap_item =[
   "name": name,
   "score": score
    ]

    print(matches.get_attribute("outerHTML"))
```

driver.quit()`